# React Native update multidimensional state value on switch press

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, state

Basically I have a list of access levels. I've put them in a list and right side of each list item I have a switch. What I am trying to achieve is to have the onPress event to update my state where the key is of the list item that has been pressed.

Section of the list data. I have no control over the key names. Sorry about that.

```
accessList:
Array(51)
0:
{FormID: 101, FormName: "ApplicationSettingCheckStoreID", FormDesc: "Activate Device", IsShow: true, Note: "ApplicationSettingCheckStoreID"}
1:
{FormID: 145, FormName: "GiftCardAddFundList", FormDesc: "Add Fund", IsShow: true, Note: "Add Fund"}
```

The way I render it

```
 <List>
    {
         this.state.accessList.map( (v, k) => {
            return (
               <ListItem key={v.FormID}>
                  <Row>
                     <Col size={80}>
                        <Text>{v.FormDesc}</Text>
                     </Col>
                     <Col size={20}>
                        <Switch  
                          value={v.IsShow}
                          onValueChange={() => this._switchToggled(v)} />
                      </Col>
                  </Row>
               </ListItem>
            );
         })
     }
   </List>
```

this is the part I am trying to fill correctly but I've failed multiple times.

```
  _switchToggled = (listItem) => { 
       ...
  }
```

I'd really appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you using for state management i.e. how is your `accessList` collection being stored? If it's coming from `redux`, you could pass an action with the index of the item you want to update like so:

```
_switchToggled = (listItem, index) => {

  this.props.dispatch(actions.updateToggle({ index, IsShow: !listItem.isShow });
}
```

Your `actions.js` file would look something like this:

```
const updateToggle = (payload) => {
  return {
    type: "UPDATE_TOGGLE",
    payload
  };
};
```

Your `reducer` would look something like this:

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  case "UPDATE_TOGGLE":

    // create a copy of the data
    let clone = state.accessList.slice();

    // mutate the single item
    let item = clone[action.payload.index];

    let newItem = {
       ...item,
       IsShow: action.payload.isShow
    };

    // splice it into the clone
    let newAccessList = clone.splice(action.payload.index, 1, newItem);

    return {
      ...state,
      accessList: clone
    };

  default:
   return state;
};
```

So in your reducer you actually make a copy of your data structure to operate on. This keeps the principle that Redux should never mutate `state` directly but rather return a new representation of `state`. Having access to the indices of your accessList array is helpful and allows you to perform the `splice` and return the item with it's `isShow` state updated. Let me know if I can help you out any more with this example.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to provide a good explanation. I really appreciate this. It now works thanks to you.

Comment: Awesome, really glad to hear it's working! Best of luck!